# Polarization of Prym varieites

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, abelian-varieties, hodge-structure, prym-varieties

I'm trying to understand polarization and rational Hodge structure of spectral curves and Prym varieties.
Excuse me that this is similar to my previous question.
I want to prove the following,

> Let $X$ be smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathscr{M}$ be moduli space of semistable Higgs bundle and $H:\mathscr{M}\rightarrow \bigoplus H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes i})$ be the Hitchin map.
> $X_s$ is the spectral curve associated to $s \in \bigoplus H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes i})$, and
> $P_s$ is the Prym variety for the covering $X_s \rightarrow X$
> The natural polarization of rational Hodge structure $H^1(X_s)$ is of the form $a\Theta_X+b\Theta_{P_{s}}$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0},\Theta_X$ is the natural polarization of $H^1(X)$, and $\Theta_{P_{s}}$ is the unique polarization of $H^1(P_s)$.

I think there is a general result, for a covering map of smooth curves $C\rightarrow C_0$ and their Prym variety $P=\operatorname{Ker}(J(C)\rightarrow J(C_0))$, there is the same relationship between their polarizations.
But I'm stuck and I could find no reference. Any help or comment will do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the isogeny $P\times JC_0\rightarrow JC$.